# Dynamically create Form based on json data in vue js html? fiddle provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I’m currently trying to get my feet wet with **[vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)** and am trying to build a form that is dynamically created.

In detail, I got json files that dictate what are the input types would go into that form; now I’m trying to wrap my head around how I could realize that in **vue.js**.

For example, when I got an json data, there need to come a select tag with different options, on clicking a particular option put text field inputs or options based on the json data in the form.

I guess thats where components would come in, but how can I dynamically render that and how would I include that without having tons of templates in my **html.
v-for** ?

The currently done fiddle is given, which have many problems.

https://jsfiddle.net/ahnu5zz9/

I need to send data as

```
rules : [{
        name:null,
        section:null,
        data   : [{head:null,value:null}]
    }],
```

After my first selection, is there any way to divide input field into components in vue.js and call components based on the selection?

So, when I select 1st option indian act, 1931, an input field comes there arms(if any). So in that case i need my v-model as `bok.data[0].head.arms` (if any). In next case when I select option 2. field with qty comes, so i need to send data as `bok.data[0].head.qty`.

In the 3rd case 1 select ker, both wild and enc comes as dropdown. On clicking this another input field comes. When I click wild, qty and item comes. So, I need to send this values as `bok.data[0].value.qty` and `bok.data[0].value.item`.

Also, I need to have multiple select options possible for wild and enc. I can able to select both wild and enc using `multiple=""`.

I AM ASKING THIS IN SEARCH OF AN ANSWER. I have asked it from another account, but no body helped me.. Please help me.. In need of a help. I am a fresher please help me.. or please give a contact of anybody who can help me..

Comment: "I have asked it from another account, but no body helped me" - creating multiple accounts to ask the same question isn't helpful at all.

Comment: you can create a component for each of your sub fields

Comment: @madalinivascu can you please help me.. can you provide me a solution

Comment: @Adam i know it is not good, can you please help me sir,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input to

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0][all3.name]">
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dcpp6zsn/)
or

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0]['value'][all3.name]">
  data   : [{head:null,value:{}}]
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dcpp6zsn/1/)

Comment: sir, thaks for the help. i also need multiple selections possible for wild and enc.. how to obatin that too

Comment: then you do something like   `bok.data[0]['value'][0][all3.name]` and change your data definition to `data   : [{head:null,value:[{qty:null,item:null}]}]`

Comment: sir actually i mean   <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" name="rule" @change="setRule(bok)" multiple="">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
          <option v-for="pl in bok.allen1" v-bind:value="pl.refId" >{{pl.name}}</option>
        </select>

Comment: checked, but at this time, the input fields are not loading in the fiddle

Comment: can you check please

Comment: hello sir, have you checked

Comment: Sir, also how can i "create a component for each of your sub fields". If you can, please provide me a solution using this

Comment: sir plz check, on each click the input fields are going on adding

Comment: @Soul yes they are, if you want multiple selected options, they will do that

Comment: no sir, just check, it keeps on adding. when i click wild and again wild, input fields goes on adding

Comment: yes i know they keep on adding because you have a multiple select, you should find a way to append only once, accept this answer if it answered your question and post another if you still have other problems, thank you